# What is the equivalent of IHttpControllerSelector for .NET 6?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

We're implementing **IHttpControllerSelector** in our ASP.NET Web Api (.NET 4.5) for Controller Discovery because some of our Api Controllers resides on a different assembly and we have custom 'routing'(namespace) for it.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "CustomApi",
    routeTemplate: "{namespace}/api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Example:

- Assembly A Controllers will be called `assemblyA/api/controllerA/get`
- Assembly B Controllers will be called `assemblyB/api/controllerA/get`

And so on...

Then we implemented the interface to resolve the controller based on our criteria (code omitted for simplicity).

```
public class NamespaceHttpControllerSelector : IHttpControllerSelector
{
    public HttpControllerDescriptor SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        //This is where we resolve the controller based on the value of the 'namespace' route.
    }
}
```

Then while migrating our codes to .NET 6, I couldn't find a way on how to do this.
I tried looking for the **IHttpControllerSelector** interface but it's only available to lower version of .NET Core but not .NET 6. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this same requirement for .NET 6? Thanks.

Comment: Update: This worked for me: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/application-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/application-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Hi @Vonzkie, did you use NamespaceRoutingConvention as equivalent for IHTTPControllerSelector.
I have same scenario where I need to migrate IHTTPControllerSelector. Can you share sample code referring the change.